# My int value doesn't remembered in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I have list that have 3 elements in the first run I add this list 3 elements and I wanna keep that list size in sharedpreferences so I can continue deleting elements from where I left off but it does not work in the first run it adds the 3 element to list but when I leave the Activity and comeback listsize seems 0 why not remembered in sharedpreferences here is what I try. firstStart part works well.

```
SharedPreferences lifememory,settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor lifeeditor;
int lifelistsize;
boolean firstStart;
ArrayList<String> lifelist;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wheel);
    lifelist= new ArrayList<>();
    lifememory=getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME",0);
    settings=getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME2", 0);
    lifelistsize=lifememory.getInt("aa",3);
    firstStart = settings.getBoolean("firstStart", true);
    life(); 
    lifememoryfunction();
}
public void life(){
    if(firstStart){
        lifelist.add("X");
        lifelist.add("X");
        lifelist.add("X");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
public void lifememoryfunction(){
    lifeeditor=lifememory.edit();
    lifeeditor.putInt("aa",lifelist.size());
    lifeeditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: can you attach the part of the code where you declare your lifelist?

Comment: I edited up side

Comment: And what do you mean when you leave the activity? Because if you leave the activity by closing the app the next time you open your app and you go to the activity it will create an empty arraylist for your life list but wont add anything cause yor first start is going to be false.

Comment: by leaving the activity I mean go another activity and come back but i think what you said is true so what can i do to keep the list do u have a idea? thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: In that case yeah it will go through the onCreate method in your activity so it will create a new empty arraylist. Im not sure what you want to do, you say that you want to keep the lifelist size so you can store it like a preference value too everytime you destroy the activity and when you create try to retrieve that value. But you also say you want this value for removing elements of your list but that list will be empty everytime you comeback to your activity.

Comment: It is important that you read the documentation to understand the lifecycle of an Activity. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle